# How to change partition of Ubuntu without losing any data?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, ssd

I have Windows installed in SSD and Linux installed in HDD and I installed them as dual boot. Now I rarely use Windows. So I want to exchange their partitions for better performance without losing any data.
I want Linux to be in SSD and Windows to be in HDD.

Screenshot of GParted for SSD:

[image: Screenshot of GParted for SSD]

Screenshot of GParted for HDD:

[image: Screenshot of GParted for HDD]

Comment: Do you have a third device that you can backup one of the disks to?

Comment: General suggestion: don't. Before you do anything like this you will need to make backups anyways. So make those (manually so you have the actual files). and then reinstall both windows and ubuntu.  and then restore the backups. It will be the quickest method

Comment: Your SSD isn't big enough to hold even the same size partition that you have for Ubuntu now on HDD. Consider a different plan.

Comment: What **DATA** do you have in your current Windows partition on SSD? Do you share files between Windows and Ubuntu? I'm thinking of a new plan for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rephrase what you are asking for. You want to:

1. Borrow or purchase the additional resources you will need:

   - External backup media of sufficient size
   - Windows install USB
   - Ubuntu install USB
   - Network connection and capability to look up problems that you encounter on a different device
   - An entire uninterrupted day

   *Good preparation is critical*. What you are about to do is *likely* to lose your data if you are unprepared.

---

2. Backup your Ubuntu data onto the backup media
3. Wipe the HDD
4. Install Windows onto the HDD
5. Test your new Windows install
6. Copy your Windows data across from the SSD, and test that you can access the data from Windows.
7. Wipe the SSD
8. Install Ubuntu onto the SSD
9. Test your new Ubuntu install
10. Restore your Ubuntu data from the backup, and test that you can access the data from Ubuntu.

Comment: Just a tip, Windows install USB is easier to make from Windows.  It can be done from Ubuntu, but have to install mkUSB or woeusb to do it well.

Comment: Note that their SSD won't even hold what the current Ubuntu partition size is on HDD. They need to consider a different plan if Ubuntu is going to be their primary OS.

Comment: @heynnema I was wondering if they would notice that before they reached Step 10. The end of the day is always when the unprepared face painful decisions.

Comment: I sent a comment to OP that their current plan really doesn't work, and that they need to consider different options.